# Is there a text based mind mapping tool for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, tools

Do you know any text based mind mapping tools for Ubuntu?

I.E. I would like to edit a text file (e.g. using vim) using a certain markup and then be able to convert it to a mind map (e.g. in png oder pdf format).

Do you know any tool that can do that?

Answer (score 3):

I tried this, it works OK

- Make a tab-indented tree of items (very simple markup) e.g.

```
Mind Map
    Test Nodes
        Indented with tabs
    Does it work?
        I think it does....
```

- Then I copied and pasted the relevant text into FreeMind
- You can export as PNG from FreeMind

[image: Test Mindmap]

The FreeMind format is reasonably simple anyway - so I guess you could write some script to take your chosen text format and write FreeMind maps.

Answer (score 2):

You can create mind maps using LaTeX packages, eg. with [TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/computer-science-mindmap/), but this won't be easy to get started with, especially if you're not familiar with LaTeX.

Maybe you'll also find [gnuclad](https://launchpad.net/gnuclad) interesting, It's only being used for trees though (as far as I know).

Comment: Thanks FSMaxB,
TikZ sounds very good. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: It's very easy to use. Got my first mind map in only a couple of minutes. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Astah Professional](http://astah.net/features/mind-map) too. You can list up all the mind map topic list, then copy and past it into Astah will make a nice looking mind map.

Answer (score 0):

Another GUI based program is Asciio, it let's you easily save in text mode or png. Some distro have a package for it, otherwise install from cpan.

I know that the next version will have a terminal based interface (because I am the author).

It is not a pure mind mapping application; you can draw what you want. There's a github project if you want to add some requirements, like mind mapping support.

A demo here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0l9W84PhOyI

Comment: Thank you for clearly stating that you are the author of this program. That is the right way to tell about your application.